# Redirect loop in wordpress behind Azure Application Gateway

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-application-gateway

I have domain `example.com` pointing to Azure Application Gateway

In Application Gateway I use url based routing which routes traffic to Azure App Service (`blog.azurewebsites.net`), and ssl termination.

App Service this is wordpress site with `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` set to "`example.com`".

Now, if I go to:

`https://example.com/post/` - works well

`https://example.com/index.php` - works well

`https://example.com` - **redirect loop takes place**

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: any update  on this ?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I run the WP Site on Azure App Service with Linux Environment.

Once I access my domain with HTTPS and the $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] return 'http' instead of 'https'. It caused the problem is the WP Site loads all images, css, js.. with **http**

I fixed my case with these lines in wp-config.php file.

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] = 'https';
```

Comment: I had endured 4 days and the spirit in me was about to give up. I had configured the azure app gateway in front of my wordpress and it wasnt just working. ... and i found this - life save.

Comment: I'm glad bc it helped you @Chamambom

Comment: saved me in the final hour for this hell of a project for a client - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `https://example.com/`? (with the slash in the end).

Without slash, I guess it is not matching the path based rules.